# Applying for UK tourist visa and travelling with documents in my maiden name?

Tags: visas, uk, chinese-citizens

I am a Chinese citizen married to a US citizen last year. I am going to apply for a UK tourist visa. The name shows on my passport is my maiden name, while any other documents the UK visa needed, such as bank statement, is with my married name. I can provide my marriage license to prove the link between my maiden name and married mane.

Can I apply for this UK visa with my situation?

Comment: I am going to have my name changed on my passport on May 26th. I already made my appointment with the Chinese Embassy. However, since it's urgent to get my uk visa, is it possible to show prove to the uk embassy that I will be going to get my name changed on my passport while applying for my uk visa first. This sounds silly, I know probably not ganna work. But still want to try to talk with someone who has more experience. Or would it be wiser to wait until I have renewed my passport in May before applying for a uk visa?

Answer (score 6):

It's usually fine to travel on your maiden name passport, though it's highly recommended to get a new one as soon as possible to make your travels less complicated.

With that said, you have the right idea, but besides your passport and marriage license, you should also submit your birth certificate.

While this set of circumstances may seem a bit odd, documents not matching, etc.,  UK border control deals thousands of cases like this every year and provided that you will supply the required documents, this shouldn't have any negative impact on your application.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe is completely common, people get married, change names, or don't, or have varied naming conventions. ECO's are accustomed to the wide range of possibilities.

You can do exactly what you describe: apply with your current passport in your maiden name, accompanied by your marriage certificate, and all your supporting documentation in your married name.

Your visa will be issued in whatever name is on the passport. You're good to travel on that passport, along with your visa. You want your ticket to match that of the passport on which you'll travel, particularly when you require a visa to enter a country.

Should you decide renew your passport prior to travel, and the new passport contains your married name, you can travel with both passports, and with a certified copy of your marriage certificate (I wouldn't take the original, to be safe, but make sure it's certified).

On arrival, you present your maiden-name passport with visa, your new passport with new name, and your marriage certificate.

In either instance, do remember to fill out any landing information in the name in your visa/passport.

There are global variations to naming conventions and practices, as well as traditions and cultures, and circumstances, in which lineal offspring have surnames different from those of their parents or antecedents. As required, applicants should have an apostille copy of their marriage license and, as appropriate, an accompanying apostille translation.

Refer to the full [guidance on UK supporting documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf).